# Sed: Find a string and replacing it without paraentheses and function name in file

Tags: sed

I need to find a string string such as:

```
foo("some text")
```

and replacing it with

```
"some text"
```

So far, all I have is

```
sed -i 's/foo(//g' $file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use groups!

```
sed -i 's/foo(\([^)]*\))/\1/' $file
```

Comment: sorry, you're right

Comment: Looks good now ;)